# Angular 4 - Select clicked list item

Tags: angular

I have list items as follows in below code snippet. On mouse click I would like to select that item (add 'active' class and deselect if any other items (siblings) selected by remove'active class. this is my nav-bar.component.html

```
  <li routerLink="/dashboard">
    <a [ngClass]="{'active-menu': selected == 'dashboard'}" (click)="selectClass('dashboard')" ><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i> Dashboard</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLink="/ui" >
    <a [ngClass] ="{'active-menu': selected == 'ui'}" (click)="selectClass('ui')"><i  class="fa fa-desktop fa-3x"></i> UI Elements</a>
  </li>
  <li routerLink="/blank"  (click)="selectClass('blank')">
    <a [ngClass] ="{'active-menu': selected === 'blank'}"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-3x"></i> Blank Page</a>
  </li>
```

And this is my nav-bar.component.ts file

```
export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
  selected: string;
   constructor() {}
   ngOnInit() {  }
   selectClass(selected: string) {
   this.selected = selected;
   console.log(this.selected);
 }
}
```

the active-menu class will be added when i click the list second time. don't whats wrong with my code. but in console, it prints the string correctly.

Comment: Did [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) not work?

Comment: your above code is working, class is getting added when you click on any li. Please check my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to use inbuilt directive routerLinkActive for adding active classes to the current route and use routerLink in `a` instead of `li`.

```
<li routerLinkActive="active-menu">
    <a routerLink="/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

Comment: yes. this working fine. Thanks for giving this better solution. @kejriwal

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working properly on my machine. Have you tried using class binding e.g.

```
<li routerLink="/dashboard">
 <a [class.active-menu]="selected == 'dashboard'" (click)="selectClass('dashboard')" >
 <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

The other way to handle your case is by using the `routerLinkActive` directive. In your example, we can format the links in the following way.

```
<li routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active-menu">
 <a><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-3x"></i> Dashboard</a>
</li>
```